# What can I say about $f:G \to Y$?

Tags: general-topology

If $f:X \to Y$ be  inyective where $X$ is nonempty perfect Polish space, $Y$ second countable and exist $G\subseteq X$ such that $G=\bigcap_{n \in \omega}D_n$ where $D_n$ is dense open sets and $f\upharpoonright G$ is continuos.

What can  I say about $f:G \to Y$ ?.Is $G$ subspace perfect of $X$.?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean injective?

Comment: In what properties of the map $f$ you are interested?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Yes, $G$ is a perfect space. Indeed, assume the converse. Then the space $G$ has an isolated point $x_0$. Then it has an open neighborhood $U_0\subset X$ such that $U_0\cap G=\{x_0\}$. Since the space $X$ is perfect, the set $U_0\setminus \{x_0\}$ is non-empty. But since the space $X$ is Baire and the set $G$ is an intersection of a countable  family of dense open subsets of the space $X$, the set $G$ is dense in a non-empty open subset $U_0\setminus \{x_0\}$ of the space $X$, a contradiction.